# How to parse JSON using init()

Tags: ios, json, swift

I can't display the `json Array` by using its object

showing this error :

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value"

```
class sample{

    var jarray:[[String:Any]]!

    init(url: String) {


        let urll = URL(string: url)
        var request              = URLRequest(url: urll!)
        request.httpMethod        = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let task                 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(Data,response,Error) in
            do
            {
                let jsonresponse = try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: [])
                let jsonarray    = jsonresponse as? [[String:Any]]
                self.jarray       = jsonarray!
                print(self.jarray)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                }

            }
            catch let parsingerror
            {
                print("error",parsingerror)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: in which line u faced this

Comment: Avoid using class names as parameter names, change our completion handler to `(data, response, error) in...`

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **Handle always errors and unwrap optionals safely.**

Second of all `Data` and `Error` (capitalized) are reserved words, use always lowercased parameter labels in closures (and uppercased class names).

Many lines in your code are redundant.

```
class Sample {

    var jarray  = [[String:Any]]()

    init(url: String) {
        guard let urll = URL(string: url) else { return }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urll) { data, _ , error in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            do
            {
                // if error is nil then data is guaranteed to be non-nil
                if let jsonarray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String:Any]] {
                    self.jarray = jsonarray
                    print(self.jarray)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error", error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Note: It's bad practice to run asynchronous tasks in `init` methods

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid using `force unwrapping` unnecessarily**. I might result in unwanted crashes in your app. In your code,

Check if `Data` is `nil`. If it is, the below line will result in runtime exception.

```
let jsonresponse = try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data!, options: [])
```

In the below line of code, check whether `jsonarray` is nil.

```
self.jarray = jsonarray!
```

If not, then add the line where your app is crashing.

Try replacing your code with:

```
class sample {
    var jarray: [[String:Any]]?

    init(url: String) {
        if let urll = URL(string: url) {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urll) { (data, response, error) in
                do {
                    if let data = data {
                        let jsonresponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                        self.jarray = jsonresponse as? [[String:Any]]
                        print(self.jarray)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("error",error)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, don't use `reserved words` as variable names like you did for `Data` and `Error`.

**Most importantly - Never use `forced unwrapping (!)` with server response. API response might not be as expected always. Try handling that.**

Comment: The code is working but  the app is crashed when accessing jarray by using the class object

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: let obj = sample(url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            jarray1 = obj.jarray //error here

Answer (score 0):

JSONSerialization is now old-fashioned way. Apple introduced [Codable](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999) protocol that handles for you serialisation and deserialisation of objects.

[Example](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999):

```
struct Photo: Codable
{
    //String, URL, Bool and Date conform to Codable.
    var title: String
    var url: URL
    var isSample: Bool

    //The Dictionary is of type [String:String] and String already conforms to Codable.
    var metaData: [String:String]

    //PhotoType and Size are also Codable types
    var type: PhotoType
    var size: Size
}
```

And in the response from the server:

```
if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
{
    let photoObject = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Photo.self, from: jsonData)
}
```